# SQL Server FOR XML explicit error in generating same name nodes

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, for-xml-explicit

i am trying to generate below XML Structure using for XML Explicit

```
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
<Worksheet ss:Name="1">
    <Table>
        <Row>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="String">231548</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="String">2014-11-03T20:03:30</Data>
            </Cell>
        </Row>
    </Table>
</Worksheet>
```

I am able to generate

```
 <Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
  <Worksheet ss:Name="1">
    <Table>
      <Row>
        <Cell>
          <Data ss:Type="String">231548</Data>
        </Cell>
      </Row>
    </Table>
  </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

I am unable to generate the above Structure.
The code i am using to generate the structure is as follows.

```
SELECT 
    Tag, 
    Parent,
    [Workbook!1!xmlns],
    [Workbook!1!xmlns:ss],
    [Worksheet!2!ss:Name],
    [Table!3!],
    [Row!4!],
    [Cell!5!],
    [Data!6!ss:Type],
    [Data!6!]
FROM ( 
SELECT top 5
    1 AS Tag,
    0 AS Parent,
    0 as SORT,
    'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet' AS [Workbook!1!xmlns],
    'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet' AS [Workbook!1!xmlns:ss],
    NULL AS [Worksheet!2!ss:Name],
    NULL AS [Table!3!],
    NULL AS [Row!4!],
    NULL AS [Cell!5!],
    NULL AS [Data!6!ss:Type],
    NULL AS [Data!6!]

UNION ALL
SELECT top 5
    2 AS Tag,
    1 AS Parent,
    AuditID * 100  as SORT,
    NULL ,
    NULL ,
    Null,
    NULL ,
    NULL ,
    NULL ,
    NULL,
    NULL 
From TempAudits
UNION ALL
SELECT top 5
    3 AS Tag,
    2 AS Parent,
    AuditID * 100+1  as SORT,
    NULL ,
    NULL ,
    NULL ,
    NULL ,
    NULL ,
    NULL ,
    NULL,
    NULL 
From TempAudits
UNION ALL
SELECT top 5
    4 AS Tag,
    3 AS Parent,
    AuditID * 100+2  as SORT,
    NULL ,
    NULL ,
    NULL ,
    NULL ,
    NULL ,
    NULL ,
    NULL,
    NULL 
    From TempAudits
UNION ALL
SELECT top 5
    5 AS Tag,
    4 AS Parent,
    AuditID * 100+3  as SORT,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL
FROM TempAudits
UNION ALL
SELECT top 5
    6 AS Tag,
    5 AS Parent,
    AuditID * 100+4  as SORT,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    'String' AS TYPE,
    AuditID AS Data
FROM TempAudits) Aa
Order by Sort
FOR XML EXPLICIT
```

Can any one please help me. 
Any help will be greatly appreciated.
 I am using this code to generate an xml that can be opened in excel.

Comment: Have a look at [`FOR XML PATH`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189885.aspx) which typically is a lot easier than explicit mode, and can do just about anything, too

Comment: @marc_s Thanks for the suggestion. I am trying that also. Can you help me with the above question?

Comment: @marc_s Can you help me to generate same XML using for XML path.

Comment: If you can provide a [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com) with the table structures and some sample data - yes, possibly

Comment: @marc_s Thanks for finding time for my help. I havae created the table and sample entries at [link]http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/126210
The XML structure that i am trying i have pasted it here [link] http://pastebin.com/uxDubTTh .

Comment: @marc_s 
Rules  to generate xml ..
A new worksheet node will be created where Study ID is changing. In this case there are two StudyID 6 and 7 .So two worksheet will be created.
A row node will be created under Worksheet Page. In this case 2 Rows will be created under each Work Sheet...
A Cell node will contain the data Node and data node will contain the value of ColName . Hence 3 node in each  Row...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you **do** want to use XML Explicit to produce this output, you could add two more tags for Cell and Data and two subsequent Union Queries.

Edit: I've added a 1 into the Worksheet!2!ss:Name column of tag 2 to ensure the output matches your requirement.

```
SELECT 
    Tag, 
    Parent,
    [Workbook!1!xmlns],
    [Workbook!1!xmlns:ss],
    [Worksheet!2!ss:Name],
    [Table!3!],
    [Row!4!],
    [Cell!5!],
    [Data!6!ss:Type],
    [Data!6!],
    [Cell!7!],
    [Data!8!ss:Type],
    [Data!8!]

FROM 
( 
    SELECT top 5
        1 AS Tag,
        0 AS Parent,
        0 as SORT,
        'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet' AS [Workbook!1!xmlns],
        'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet' AS [Workbook!1!xmlns:ss],
        NULL AS [Worksheet!2!ss:Name],
        NULL AS [Table!3!],
        NULL AS [Row!4!],
        NULL AS [Cell!5!],
        NULL AS [Data!6!ss:Type],
        NULL AS [Data!6!],
        NULL AS [Cell!7!],
        NULL AS [Data!8!ss:Type],
        NULL AS [Data!8!]

    UNION ALL
    SELECT top 5
        2 AS Tag,
        1 AS Parent,
        AuditID * 100  as SORT,
        NULL AS [Workbook!1!xmlns],
        NULL AS [Workbook!1!xmlns:ss],
        1 AS [Worksheet!2!ss:Name],
        NULL AS [Table!3!],
        NULL AS [Row!4!],
        NULL AS [Cell!5!],
        NULL AS [Data!6!ss:Type],
        NULL AS [Data!6!],
        NULL AS [Cell!7!],
        NULL AS [Data!8!ss:Type],
        NULL AS [Data!8!]
    From TempAudits

    UNION ALL
    SELECT top 5
        3 AS Tag,
        2 AS Parent,
        AuditID * 100+1  as SORT,
         NULL AS [Workbook!1!xmlns],
        NULL AS [Workbook!1!xmlns:ss],
        NULL AS [Worksheet!2!ss:Name],
        NULL AS [Table!3!],
        NULL AS [Row!4!],
        NULL AS [Cell!5!],
        NULL AS [Data!6!ss:Type],
        NULL AS [Data!6!],
        NULL AS [Cell!7!],
        NULL AS [Data!8!ss:Type],
        NULL AS [Data!8!]
    From TempAudits

    UNION ALL
    SELECT top 5
        4 AS Tag,
        3 AS Parent,
        AuditID * 100+2  as SORT,
        NULL AS [Workbook!1!xmlns],
        NULL AS [Workbook!1!xmlns:ss],
        NULL AS [Worksheet!2!ss:Name],
        NULL AS [Table!3!],
        NULL AS [Row!4!],
        NULL AS [Cell!5!],
        NULL AS [Data!6!ss:Type],
        NULL AS [Data!6!],
        NULL AS [Cell!7!],
        NULL AS [Data!8!ss:Type],
        NULL AS [Data!8!]
        From TempAudits

    UNION ALL
    SELECT top 5
        5 AS Tag,
        4 AS Parent,
        AuditID * 100 + 3  as SORT,
        NULL AS [Workbook!1!xmlns],
        NULL AS [Workbook!1!xmlns:ss],
        NULL AS [Worksheet!2!ss:Name],
        NULL AS [Table!3!],
        NULL AS [Row!4!],
        NULL AS [Cell!5!],
        NULL AS [Data!6!ss:Type],
        NULL AS [Data!6!],
        NULL AS [Cell!7!],
        NULL AS [Data!8!ss:Type],
        NULL AS [Data!8!]
    FROM TempAudits

    UNION ALL
    SELECT top 5
        6 AS Tag,
        5 AS Parent,
        AuditID * 100 + 4 as SORT,
        NULL AS [Workbook!1!xmlns],
        NULL AS [Workbook!1!xmlns:ss],
        NULL AS [Worksheet!2!ss:Name],
        NULL AS [Table!3!],
        NULL AS [Row!4!],
        NULL AS [Cell!5!],
        'String' AS [Data!6!ss:Type],
        AuditID AS [Data!6!],
        NULL AS [Cell!7!],
        NULL AS [Data!8!ss:Type],
        NULL AS [Data!8!]
    FROM 
    TempAudits

    UNION ALL
    SELECT top 5
       7 AS Tag,
        4 AS Parent,
        AuditID * 100 + 5 as SORT,
        NULL AS [Workbook!1!xmlns],
        NULL AS [Workbook!1!xmlns:ss],
        NULL AS [Worksheet!2!ss:Name],
        NULL AS [Table!3!],
        NULL AS [Row!4!],
        NULL AS [Cell!5!],
        NULL AS [Data!6!ss:Type],
        NULL AS [Data!6!],
        NULL AS [Cell!7!],
        NULL AS [Data!8!ss:Type],
        NULL AS [Data!8!]
    FROM TempAudits

    UNION ALL
    SELECT top 5
        8 AS Tag,
        7 AS Parent,
        AuditID * 100 + 6 as SORT,
        NULL AS [Workbook!1!xmlns],
        NULL AS [Workbook!1!xmlns:ss],
        NULL AS [Worksheet!2!ss:Name],
        NULL AS [Table!3!],
        NULL AS [Row!4!],
        NULL AS [Cell!5!],
        NULL AS [Data!6!ss:Type],
        NULL AS [Data!6!],
        NULL AS [Cell!7!],
        'String' AS [Data!8!ss:Type],
        AuditDate AS [Data!8!]
    FROM 
    TempAudits 
) Aa
Order by Sort
FOR XML EXPLICIT
```